# PHP and Wordpress How can I read certain lines from remote file

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read certain lines from a remote file being the code

```
                    // get bio from remote servers from line 835 to 859
                $userbio = fopen("http://example.com/".$db->username, 'r');
                $lineNo = 0;
                $startLine = 865;
                $endLine = 892;
                while ($line = fgets($userbio)) {
                    $lineNo++;
                    if ($lineNo >= $startLine) {
                        echo $line;
                    }
                    if ($lineNo == $endLine) {
                       break;
                    }
                }
                fclose($userbio);
```

And this works great on a single php file, but when inside Wordpress all I get is Resource ID #164.
Any other way of doing this remote read?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try file_get_contents() function, for guide visit [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_remote_fopen()`:

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_fopen